# Table over multiple pages with different margins

Tags: tables, margins, geometry

I have a long table over multiple pages and I need a different margin on the first page as the rest.

So I also try to use: `\newgeometry{paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=40mm,top=50mm,bottom=33mm}` and `\restoregeometry` in different variations without success.

The table is filled dynamically so I don't know where the first page ended.
[image]

Comment: just set it up as on the second page and put `\vspace*{-3cm}` before `Text here!` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thx a lot it work's! I could swear I also tried this... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set up the margins as as on the second page and put

```
\vspace*{-3cm}
```

before `Text here!` to move the first page up .